# Android WebView issue with date input

Tags: android, webview, calendar

I'm using Android WebView to show HTML page, I have an input date, it allow use to choose date from Calendar. But the month show strange value

This is HTML elements

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" id="txtDob" name="dob" value="" required="true" max="2019-08-19">
```

In the WebView, it still show M08 instead August

Screenshot https://scontent.fsgn5-6.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/69418701_513202176118882_5481155220689911808_n.png?_nc_cat=109&_nc_oc=AQmzXFdC7U9CDCDUwM23X7PZZgQS16qbdYV34cFz2iY-aQTxMAenRNyh2mDUow2nnYI&_nc_ht=scontent.fsgn5-6.fna&oh=5f5fef0c507927a4489230cfe7f9e332&oe=5E1586AB

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is date picker format issue. You have to set format local format with country code and language like (in android).

```
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "GB");
```

So in Html set language and country code

Comment: If it worked then accept my answer and upvote thanks.